# Hardware for SQL Server database 

Tags: sql-server, hardware

I need to calculate hardware for SQL Server. The application is business data-driven application with 500 requests per second. We plan to buy server with 4 intel Xeon CPU and 64 Gb RAM. Is it sufficiently?

Comment: What storage? Are the requests reads or writes? How big will the database be? How fast will the database grow? And how to do plan to provide High Availability/Disaster Recovery? If you don't have any plan for HA, how are you going to do maintenance and patching?

Comment: What is the most limiting factor of a database? And what do you nto talk about at all? DISC IO. The question is totally unanswerable in this form. Point. The server is either powerfull or total crap depending on the discs. Get a server that can stock 30+ discs - SuperMicro sells them (2 rack units = space for 72 discs + the server hardware - mobo etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The specifications you've come up with looks like a decent start for "some kind of database" that you don't know much about.  But you can get a very nasty surprise, finding out that this doesn't work at all.

It's impossible to tell with the amount of information given.

A query is not a fixed cost.  If it was 500 light queries per second - you could scale down significantly.  If they are really complex queries, you might need a lot more than you've specified.  If it's a poorly written application, it might need a rewrite to be able to run decently fast.

To best be able to answer this, you need to establish a good baseline for the application; How much resources does it consume under realistic load?  The developers of the application should have some knowledge about this as well.

You should also keep storage in mind - which needs to satisfy the throughput required, and have at least a basic level of redundancy to avoid data loss.

I'm assuming you've got backup and high availability-concerns covered.